# HOW to Compiling the latest OpenSSL 1.1.0l for TOOLCHAIN Android

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk

I am trying to generate the shared library for the (.so) files of the OpenSSL1.1.0l for the TOOLCHAIN Android. I found that they have added three options for compiling for the Android in the android script.

```
export NDK=/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/File/Android\ NDK/android-ndk-r14b
${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --platform=android-21  --install-dir=/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/OsCaM/Toolchain/android-STAPI
export TOOLCHAIN_PATH=/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/OsCaM/Toolchain/android-STAPI/bin
export TOOL=arm-linux-androideabi
export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOL}
export CC=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-gcc
export CXX=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-g++
export LINK=${CXX}
export LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ld
export AR=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ar
export RANLIB=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-ranlib
export STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASENAME-strip
export ARCH_FLAGS="-Os -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16"
export ARCH_LINK="-march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"
export CFLAGS=" ${ARCH_FLAGS} -g -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fPIE"
export LDFLAGS=" ${ARCH_LINK} -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,-s -fPIE -pie"
./Configure android
make clean
PATH=$TOOLCHAIN_PATH:$PATH make
```

But in several transformations I have not succeeded

```
/usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
    "-oMakefile" crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h.in > crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
/usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
    "-oMakefile" crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h.in > crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
/usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
    "-oMakefile" include/openssl/opensslconf.h.in > include/openssl/opensslconf.h
make depend && make _all
make[1]: Entering directory '/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/File/openssl/openssl-1.1.0l'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/File/openssl/openssl-1.1.0l'
make[1]: Entering directory '/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/File/openssl/openssl-1.1.0l'
/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/OsCaM/Toolchain/android-STAPI/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -I. -Icrypto/include -Iinclude -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\"" -Wall -O3 -pthread -mandroid -fPIC --sysroot= -Wa,--noexecstack  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_cbc.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_cbc.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_cbc.o crypto/aes/aes_cbc.c
/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/OsCaM/Toolchain/android-STAPI/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -I. -Icrypto/include -Iinclude -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\"" -Wall -O3 -pthread -mandroid -fPIC --sysroot= -Wa,--noexecstack  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_cfb.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o crypto/aes/aes_cfb.c
/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/OsCaM/Toolchain/android-STAPI/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -I. -Icrypto/include -Iinclude -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\"" -Wall -O3 -pthread -mandroid -fPIC --sysroot= -Wa,--noexecstack  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_core.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_core.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_core.o crypto/aes/aes_core.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:55:0,
                 from crypto/aes/aes_core.c:41:
/usr/include/bits/floatn.h:74:1: error: unknown machine mode '__TC__'
 typedef _Complex float __cfloat128 __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__TC__)));
 ^
/usr/include/bits/floatn.h:86:9: error: unknown type name '__float128'
 typedef __float128 _Float128;
         ^
make[1]: *** [Makefile:664: crypto/aes/aes_core.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/HDD/OtHeR/BuIlD/File/openssl/openssl-1.1.0l'
make: *** [Makefile:132: all] Error 2
```

I want to make a copy on a device " STAPI"

I've tried a script " OSEbuild.sh " without result

Comment: [Android on the OpenSSL wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) used to provide instructions for Android. Omitting the call to source `setenv-android.sh` looks suspicious to me. The script sets other variables like `MACHINE`, `RELEASE`, `SYSTEM`, `ARCH`, `CROSS_COMPILE` and `HOSTCC`, iirc. I am not sure how current the wiki article is, however.

Comment: The empty `--sysroot=` in your code is probably part of the problem. Instead of trying to debug this mess, I would use a modern NDK that does not require the separate toolchain step and build OpenSSL via https://github.com/viaduck/openssl-cmake